# YUI 2.8 book - still relevant for YUI 3.x?

Tags: yui

I am looking for a YUI book and this one seems to have reasonable reviews:

[http://www.amazon.com/YUI-Learning-Library-Daniel-Barreiro/dp/1849510709](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849510709)

However, I will be using YUI 3.x. Will this book still be a useful introduction to YUI generally or is it more likely to confuse with out of date information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will probably just confuse you. YUI 3's API is rather different from YUI 2.

Comment: Do you really feel like you need a book? The online documentation and YUI help forums are quite complete. I've never needed/used a book for YUI. Besides, Daniel Barreiro (satyam) has contributed significantly to the documentation, and AFAIK continues to do so.

Answer (score 4):

A YUI 2.x book is going to be no help, I suggest the online docs & visiting the IRC channel (#yui on freenode).

Evan Goer is writing a YUI cookbook that is shaping up really nicely but won't be out for another several months. If you really want a book on YUI that one will be the one to get.

Answer (score 0):

The book was published in May '12 and has a lot of details on YUI3: 
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920013303.do

If you have questions, feel free to ask at the YUI Forums: http://yuilibrary.com/forum/